# Как получить из инпута значение строки и ее длину, если она начинается с "e"?

Tags: javascript

Как узнать длину строки, или как вообще с ней взаимодействовать если она начинается с e. Я хочу получить полное значение из инпута независимо от того, что в нем содержится.

Ниже привел пример с проблемой (даже не знал что такая вообще есть) гугление на английском не дало результатов.

Чтобы воспроизвести ошибку в инпут можно вписать значение 5555 и вы увидите длину строки, и ее значение.

Но если вписать e555, то в консоль выводится пустая строка, а ее длина равна 0.

```js
function foo(e) {
  console.log('Значение инпута: ' + e.target.value);
  console.log('Длина значения: ' + e.target.value.length);
  console.log('Тип переменной: ' + typeof e.target.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" oninput="foo(event)">
```

Comment: Мы понимаем, что это вызвано `type="number"`?

Comment: @Igor   Мы предполагаем) но тем не менее DOM элемент существует, значит должен быть способ его подцепить?
Или единственное решение это отказаться от number?

Comment: не понимаю, а зачем ?

Answer (score -1):

Я не уверен кончено, но я просто поменял аргумент функции и у меня все заработало.
Похоже проблема была именно в аргументе.

```
function foo(event) {
    console.log('Значение инпута: ' + event.target.value);
    console.log('Длина значения: ' + event.target.value.length);
    console.log('Тип переменной: ' + typeof event.target.value);
  }
```